# How to move a project up/down in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am having a long list of projects up in project explorer. And would like to move certain project up.
Is there a short cut for this in eclipse??

Comment: In the _Project Explorer_ the projects are sorted alphabetically and this can not be changed (maybe there is a plugin to do this). You can use Working Sets to group your projects (by choosing _Top Level Elements > Working Sets_ in the view menu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1>You can filter your projects according to working sets.
[working sets explained](https://dzone.com/articles/eclipse-working-sets-explained)

2>On the drop down menu of Package Explorer, you can select Filters and choose Closed Projects. This will automatically hide all the projects that are closed which can help you to do sorting